# passing data or parameters from embedded file to main page in flutter

Tags: flutter, parameter-passing, fluttermap

To be able to easily explain what I need, I prepared the following image.

[image]

Shortly,
I have a homepage.dart page and I embedded a map1.dart page into it.
when user taps on the map, it creates a small node and adds the point into "createdMarkerPoints[]" array.
I want to pass any data (List createdMarkerPoints[]) from map1.dart to a component on homepage.dart file, when:

1. user clicks a button at homepage.dart (triggered at homepage.dart)
2. user taps on the map at map1.dart (triggered at map1.dart)

Thank you for helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could move `List createdMarkerPoints` to `homepage.dart` and then give a function that adds to createdMarkerPoints to `map1.dart`. This is a callback function.

This article gives some examples: https://medium.com/@dnkibere/passing-a-function-as-an-argument-flutter-e011ad2afd86